# scapy summary DNS Ans

Tags: python, scapy

when I do

`.summary()`

with scapy I get the following result back

```
'DNS Ans "ee-in-f139.1e100.net."'
```

Is there any filter within scapy that only returns

```
"ee-in-f139.1e100.net"
```

or is my only option to strip the string?

@ RyPeck

At this moment

```
get hostname(ip):

    ip = x.split('.')
    ip.reverse()
    x = '.'.join(ip) + ".in-addr.arpa"

    answer = sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname= ip , qtype='PTR')), verbose = 0)
    filter = answer[DNS].summary()
    filter = filter.strip('DNS Ans ')
    filter = filter.strip('."')
```

which gives me back the hostname and I filter out the DNS Ans. I was hoping that scapy returns just the hostname without me filtering it.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you ran to get the answer?

Comment: Do you need to use Scapy to do the reverse lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
def gethostname(ip):
    ip = ip.split('.')
    ip.reverse()
    ip = '.'.join(ip) + ".in-addr.arpa"
    answer = sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname= ip , qtype='PTR')), verbose = 0)
    #answer.show()
    return answer["DNS"].an.rdata[:-1]
```

What I did:
Instead of using `.summary()`, I just disassembled the answer:  `["DNS"]` gives the dns layer, `.an` gives the answer that was given, `.rdata` is the actual data that you want, and `[:-1]` strips off the final dot, because, as specified in RFC1034 a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) always ends with a trailing `.`. If you want to see the whole packet, you should just un-comment `anser.show()`